# Question regarding bounded derivative

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, derivatives

I am aware that proving uniform contnuity can sometimes be easier using the Mean Value Theorem. Eventually it boils down to proving that the derivative is bounded. For illustration purposes:

Let 
$f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ and  ${\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}f^\prime(x)}=0$

By definition that means $\exists c \in \mathbb R$ such that $|f^\prime(x)|<c$ and my question is then for which $x \in \mathbb R$ is the above valid.

I'm playing with the idea that it suffices if ${\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}f^\prime(x)}=a$, where $a \in \mathbb R$ which would then mean our sequence $(f^\prime(x))_{x}$ is bounded. The thought that, however, seems to nullify that thought process is that we're in $\mathbb R$ and this may not hold for ${\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty}f^\prime(x)}$.

Am I missing something? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wouldn’t something like $e^{-x}$ be the kind of counterexample you are looking for? If you knew $\lim_{x\to\infty}f’(x)$, $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f’(x)$ both exist (and are finite), and that $f’(x)$ is continuous, then you could say $f’(x)$ is bounded.

Answer (score 1):

But there exist functions $f$ which are uniformly continuous but not having bounded derivative, so the strategy regarding bounded derivative technique sometimes does not work:

Find a $\phi\in C^{\infty}({\bf{R}})$ such that $\phi=1$ on $|x|\geq 1$ and $\phi=0$ on $|x|<\delta$ for small $\delta\in(0,1)$, then let $f(x)=\dfrac{\sin(x^{3})}{x}$ on $|x|>\delta/2$, $f(x)=0$ for $|x|\leq\delta/2$, and consider $\phi\cdot f$, then $\phi\cdot f:{\bf{R}}\rightarrow{\bf{R}}$ is uniformly continuous but for all $x>1$, 
\begin{align*}
(\phi\cdot f)'(x)=3x\cos(x^{3})-\dfrac{\sin(x^{3})}{x^{2}},
\end{align*}
so $\phi\cdot f$ has unbounded derivative.

Comment: Noted, thank you. But with the limit definition of the derivative I mentioned above I cannot surmise that the derivative is indeed bounded, right? So how else can I prove that the derivative is bounded?

Comment: Pointwise bounded always fails to deduce the whole boundedness. The whole boundedness may depend on context, I never heard of any general method to deal with that.